# Oracle Running Subtraction

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below data. I want to subtract the first row from Total Qty (80) and then subtract the rest of the rows from QTY from the previous row of QTY1.

```
QTY                      QTY1          DATE              TOTAL QTY
 2                        78         01-JAN-20             80
 1                        77         15-JAN-20
 46                       31         22-JAN-20
 16                       15         27-JAN-20
```

Is there a way to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no *previous* row, unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: Can you also please provide expected resut?

Comment: Expected result is in column QTY1. Second row of QTY (1) minus previous row of QTY1 (78) and then it continues.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
select
  t.*
 ,first_value(TOTAL_QTY)over(order by DT) - sum(QTY)over(order by DT) as QTY1
from t;
```

Full example with your sample data:

```sql
with T(QTY, DT, TOTAL_QTY) as (
   select 2 , to_date('01-JAN-20','dd-mon-yy'),80   from dual union all
   select 1 , to_date('15-JAN-20','dd-mon-yy'),null from dual union all
   select 46, to_date('22-JAN-20','dd-mon-yy'),null from dual union all
   select 16, to_date('27-JAN-20','dd-mon-yy'),null from dual
)
select
  t.*
 ,first_value(TOTAL_QTY)over(order by DT) - sum(QTY)over(order by DT) as QTY1
from t;
```

Result:

```
QTY  DT          TOTAL_QTY  QTY1
2    2020-01-01  80         78
1    2020-01-15             77
46   2020-01-22             31
16   2020-01-27             15
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your question seems to rely on the ordering of the rows.  Let me assume you have a column that represents the ordering.

Use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(total_qty) over () - sum(qty) over (order by <ordering col>) as qty1
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=41e3180a04b939e6c2034168f7e7bfaf) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but it doesn't seem to be subtracting from the previous row of QTY1 field. It should subtract the current row of the QTY field from the previous row of QTY1 field. I just added the date field in the above data. Only the first row of QTY column must get subtracted from the TOTAL QTY and then Current row of QTY minus previous row of QTY1.

Comment: @Nick . . . It works fine when I run it.  I included a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (the CTE is just your data): if you add any more stuff later (in the total_qty column), then that would also get added to the total_qty calcuation (as would be typical for additions to, and subtractions from, inventory.

```
with d as

 (select  2   qty,                     78 qty1   ,      to_date('01-JAN-20','dd-mon-rr') datecol,             80 total_qty from dual union all
 select 1,                        77,         to_date('15-JAN-20','dd-mon-rr'),null from dual union all
 select 46 ,                      31,         to_date('22-JAN-20','dd-mon-rr'),null from dual union all
 select 16 ,                      15 ,        to_date('27-JAN-20','dd-mon-rr'),null from dual 
 )
select sum(total_qty) over (order by datecol) - sum(qty) over (order by datecol)
from d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select
  qty, 
  first_value(total_qty) over(order by date) 
    - sum(qty) over(order by date) as qty1,
  date, total_qty
from t
order by date
```